# What are ground_object_cloud and base_scan_marking?

Tags: navigation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Looking into the pr2 navigation configuration: costmap_common_params.yaml, we saw that there are 4 sources: tilt_scan, base_scan, base_scan_marking, ground_object_cloud.

We suffered from fantom obstacles when navigating. When removing the ground_object_cloud source the fantom disapeared.
What is this source for ? By the way, what is base_scan_marking for ?

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10955/what-are-ground_object_cloud-and-base_scan_marking-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Marking etc are documented in the [Navigation Robot Setup Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2016-01-12**:
where is ground_object_cloud documented?